# How and where does OpenCV preprocess the input array for an ONNX in below code?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, face-detection

I am doing a face detection project using [CenterFace](https://github.com/Star-Clouds/CenterFace). The authors have given code in their github where they have used OpenCV's DNN module to read the model from it's ONNX file.

```
class CenterFace(object):
def __init__(self, landmarks=True):
    ...
       self.net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX('models/onnx/centerface.onnx')
    ...
```

The problem is that using onnxruntime for inference the model requires a input of size **(10, 3, 32, 32)**.

However, in the opencv implementation the shape of the blob is **(1, 3, 480, 640)** after running blobFromImage() method and after setInput() method. I have checked it personally with a print statement.

I wish to know where the preprocessing step occurs inbetween these lines of code so I can hopefully find ways to optimize it. I have never before used OpenCV nor C++ for DL and only have experience with pytorch and python.

```
def inference_opencv(self, img, threshold):
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, scalefactor=1.0, size=(self.img_w_new, self.img_h_new), mean=(0, 0, 0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    self.net.setInput(blob)

    print(blob.shape) #  ACTUAL blob shape at this point ---> (1, 3, 480, 640)


    # EXPECTED blob shape (by analyzing onnx model) ---> (10, 3, 32, 32)
    heatmap, scale, offset, lms = self.net.forward(["537", "538", "539", "540"])
```

Comment: What's the original size of your images? Can't you resize it (or the blob) to 32 x 32? cv2.dnn.blobFromImage has a `size` argument, which is spatial size for the output image, are you setting that to 32 x 32?

Comment: looks like it might be a fully convolutional network. the batch size of 10 seems oddly specific. probably a placeholder. -- DO NOT resize entire images down to 32x32.

Comment: @stateMachine my image is of size (3, 640, 480) after using blobFromImage it becomes (1, 3, 480, 640) as I've already mentioned in the post above. In their code the blob size of (1, 3, 480, 640) works without any change to the code and the self.net.forward([...]) Gives the required output. But the actual onnx model requires (10,3,32,32) which is what's puzzling me.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes I agree with you. But what else do you think I should do? Do you have any suggestions? I'm completely out of answers here.

Comment: what is their code? do they not use OpenCV? did you run their code or did you write your own? if their code no longer works, submit an issue to their github.

Comment: did you thoroughly analyze their code? https://github.com/Star-Clouds/CenterFace/blob/master/prj-python/centerface.py

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz no sir, their code works. But their implementation of using opencv's dnn is rather slow. When I tried loading the model through onnxruntime and running it with a random input generated as a numpy array np.random.randn(10,3,32,32) was able to get very much speed. Thus, I want to know how I can preprocess an actual image to the required dimension, to get the output fast with onnxruntime.

Comment: what GPU do you have?

Comment: In my CPU. Running their opencv code on my CPU (Its preprocessing the input for sure) gives me around 6 FPS. Whilst running the onnx model on the same CPU gives me around 55 FPS. And they have cited 60FPS on CPU in their paper too.